# Disabled Check Box Loses Value When Saving

Tags: xpages

I have a check box that is disabled. I click a button that sets the value of that check box to be 'checked'. When I go to save, the check box loses its value. Anyone have any ideas? Here is a simple mockup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument
            var="MainForm"
            formName="MainForm" />
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:checkBox
        text="CheckBox"
        id="CheckBox"
        value="#{MainForm.CheckBox}"
        disabled="true"
        checkedValue="Y"
        uncheckedValue="N">
    </xp:checkBox>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button
        id="setBc"
        value="Set CheckBox">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="CheckBox">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("CheckBox").setValue("Y");}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button
        value="Save"
        id="button5">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:MainForm.save();}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Its OK if behaviour is correct now, but was it uncorrect till now? what about compatibility with all apps developed till now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabled controls are not included in page submissions.

You can combine your disabled check box with a xp:inputHidden control which is a hidden input field that is included in page submissions.

Comment: It seems as though disabled Combo Boxes are submitted with the page though? That's where I was confused.

Thanks for the inputHidden idea.

Comment: Bear in mind that, even if the value is posted to the server, if the component with which the value is associated is considered disabled, the value will still be ignored during UPDATE_COMPONENT_MODEL, if the data source makes the understandable assumption that the values of disabled fields have not changed. I don't know whether this is how it actually behaves, but will investigate.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I believe it is true that if the value has not changed on a disabled field, the value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a specific problem to Domino 8.5.3 (if that is what you are using).
We have noticed that since we upgraded to 8.5.3 we get a problem (on normal classic domino pages) where fields tagged as "disabled" don't get saved down to the doc.
We have had to build around this by not using a "proper" field that is disabled for values that has to later be saved.
Another workaround was to remove the disabled setting before posting in the post script.

We are fairly sure this all started to happened with the release of 8.5.3

Comment: According to the W3C HTMl specifications, chapter 17.13.2, only a  successful control is "valid" for submission with a form and controls that are disabled cannot be - as per the specification - successful. Therefore the Domino behaviour is correct.